# HTTPS File streaming works with curl but failswith java http url connection with response code 413

Tags: java, curl, https, stream

We have a usecase where we need to stream a file over https to a vendor and it is part of a larger multi step processes. Everything works fine if the file size is lessthan 128kb, but the file streaming fails with responsecode 413 if the file size is larger than 130KB. The intresting thing is if we try with curl , it works even for file sizes larger than 130KB. Any ideas what could be the problem.

Comment: If you do not show the code you are using, chances of spotting the problem are close to zero

Comment: The haruspices are hazy: could be _incorrect synchronization_ or an _off-by-n_ error.